# Prometheus histogram duration

Tags: prometheus, histogram, promql

I have a histogram that observes a process duration with some labels (source, size, etc..)
and I want to display a graph of the average processing time.

Right now I'm doing it like so:

```
  rate(process_duration_seconds_sum[5m])
/
  rate(process_duration_seconds_count[5m])
```

But I noticed that sometimes the `rate(process_duration_seconds_sum[5m])` results in 0 and I get a straight line graph.

My understanding of this is that there is no change in the values in the 5m range and so the derivative is 0.
But there is a value (_sum), there's also count of observations (_count).

My question is if there's a better way to get an average of process duration?

Comment: Sorry, you didn't see increase in process time for five minutes, no processes were run at that time. Why are you not happy with 0 at your graph?

Comment: For example, if I have a single observation. The rate of the sum will be 0. But i would like to show the average of that one observation